# Can Lodestone Lure be used on adjacent targets?

Tags: dnd-4e, forced-movement

The Battlemind power Lodestone Lure states: (emphasis added)

> **Hit**: Constitution modifier damage, and ***you must pull the target 1 square***. Until the end of your next turn, the target can move only to squares that are adjacent to you.

If you cannot pull the target, for example if the target is already adjacent to you, can you use the power? Likewise, can the augment 2 version ("must pull the target 4 squares") be used on a target fewer than 4 squares away?

The rule for forced movement seems to refer to cases where you can use "up to" the amount of forced movement in cases where the wording says, eg, "pull 4" or "pull up to 4." But I can't seem to find a rule about "must pull 4." Is there any ruling that can clarify this issue?

Answer (score 4):

You *can try* to pull a target that's already adjacent to you.

That pull will result in no movement and 'fail' in that sense, but that's different than not pulling - you don't get to choose if you'll pull or not, but pulls that don't result in any movement (say, the target is a dwarf with the related feature, or some magic item that prevents forced movement, or some physical barrier) still count as a valid pull-attempts, even if you deliberately choose a target that won't get pulled if you try.

Comment: Correct. If it meant you couldn't target adjacent foes the power would explicitly say so.

Answer (score 0):

Just to note the power doesn't actually say ***you MUST pull the target***, it says;

> Hit: Constitution modifier damage, and you pull the target 1 square.
>
> Or 4 squares if you augment by 1 or 2.

To answer the second part of your question. The RAW for forced movement states;

> **Distance in Squares:** The power you’re using specifies how many squares you **can** move a target. **You can choose to move the target fewer squares or not to move it at all.** You can’t move the target vertically.

Even if the power says *you pull the target X squares* you can move them fewer if you choose.

Comment: This is incorrect- it was errataed to say must.

Comment: @JLan speaks the truth: errata added three *must*s to *lodestone lure.* My regular gaming group switched to *4e* about three months ago, and I just swapped my swordsage for a battlemind so I needed an answer to the question. In other words, this answer can still distract new players. Could this answer be updated? (I suggest adding a mention of the errata since its not mentioned anywhere else on the page but in the aforementioned comment.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan unfortunately I didn't have the errata when I wrote this answer and it's been so long since I've played 4e that I hardly remember how any of the rules interact. I'll dig out my books and read through them over the next few days, see if I can't jog my memory, but I doubt I'll be able to sufficiently update this answer.

Comment: If you just add something like *If you're using as* lodestone lure *as printed…* then later mentioned that errata added the *must*s, that'd be cool. (It just seemed wrong to downvote this answer given its age and that it was obviously written in good faith.)

Comment: Just to clarify- they added the "Must" because if they didn't, especially on the augmented version, you could refrain from pulling them at all and prevent them from moving (an enemy five squares away who could only move to squares adjacent to you- i.e. they couldn't move at all).  This is unfortunate- a much better errata would've been to specify that the enemy had to end the pull adjacent to you- but that's not what they did.

Comment: @JLan O, yeah, pre-errata, *lodestone lure* was a mess; I've read the complaints about it in old threads; they got *ugly.* And even the errata's no help when trying to determine what happens on the foe's turn if, on the battlemind's turn, he successfully uses *lure* on that foe then the battlemind moves away from the foe! (I'll likely pose that question soon unless I'm missing something that's bloody obvious that you can enlighten me on here.)