# How does lodestone lure work if the attacker's moved away from the target?

Tags: dnd-4e, balance, powers, battlemind

The level 3 battlemind discipline ***lodestone lure***, an at-will attack power, has the following entry:

> **Hit:** Constitution modifier damage, and you must pull the target 1 square. Until the end of your next turn, the target can move only to squares that are adjacent to you. (*Psionic Power* 37 and updated by errata; q.v. [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48171/8610))

I don't know to what degree that second sentence should limit the target. I use *should limit* rather than just *limits* because my research shows that opinions on how the power works are varied, controversial, and sometimes heated. And, as Wizards of the Coast itself is unlikely to clarify or issue further errata for the *lodestone lure* power at this point, I look to experienced users for help in determining a balanced reading of the power. **Here *balanced* means here that the power's impact on the game approximately equals the impact of the class's other powers of the same level.**

## The Scenario

On her turn a level 3 battlemind takes a standard action to use the at-will discipline *lodestone lure* on a target 2 squares away. The battlemind pulls the target adjacent to her (as the power's erratum now says that she must). Then, by whatever means, the battlemind travels 2 or more squares away from the target. On the target's turn, what's a balanced way for the target to behave? Here are some options:

- **Essentially immobilized.** A typical target is immobilized in all but name. That is, no matter where the target's movement would take it, its first square of movement won't move it to a square adjacent to the battlemind so the target is stuck where it is unless *either* it can move without moving (e.g. by teleporting) *or* it is moved *via* forced movement. This reading is mentioned in a *Penny Arcade* forum thread [here](https://forums.penny-arcade.com/discussion/175095/d-amp-d-4e-gw-discussion-dont-worry-ladies-im-only-slowed-in-the-good-ways/p39) that contains strong language. Consensus there seems to be that this reading, while possibly being *technically* accurate, isn't balanced (see above). Even as a new *4e* player, I tend to agree, but I'm not 100% sure if that thread's assessment is correct.
- **Like a charge but not.** A typical target can move normally *except* that each square of the target's movement must bring the target closer to the battlemind, much like a creature making a charge. This reading is mentioned in a *RPG.Net* thread [here](https://forum.rpg.net/index.php?threads/lodestone-lure-question.567493/) that gets heated. Note that a user in that thread says that Wizards of the Coast customer service agrees with this reading. I absolutely believe that that's what the user was told, but I don't know how much weight an anonymous Wizards of the Coast customer service representative's ruling carries in the *Dungeons & Dragons, Fourth Edition* community. (To be clear, I'm used to the *Third Edition* community where that weight is 0 lbs.) This seems balanced enough to this new *4e* player, but that isn't what the power actually says that it does, and the disconnect makes me wary.

Those were the options that I found, but I'm certain that other readings of the power are possible. Users should feel free to have their answers address alternatives. **In sum, what reading of the *lodestone lure* power is balanced? Further, how can the *lodestone lure* power's *Hit* entries be rephrased to reflect a new balanced reading?**

---

***Note:*** When assessing that second bullet's reading, please also consider what happens if a target is affected by multiple characters' lodestone lure *powers simultaneously.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noted, the wording is vague. The group I'm part of (which I believe is the largest 4e community still active), however, actually went with option 3, which is that the target cannot move, in *any* way, to a square that is not adjacent to the battlemind that lodestone lured it.
This sounds like your option 1, however, forced movement is still movement. And teleportation is still movement. The target can only leave its square if it is entering a square adjacent to the battlemind, teleportation just allows them to skip the intervening squares. This is supported by the *Rules Compendium* definition of movement (p. 200)

> Move: Any instance of movement, whether it is done willingly or unwillingly. Whenever a creature, an objecto, or an effect leaves a square to enter another, it is moving. Shifting, teleporting, and being pushed are all examples of moves

As far as balance, well, that's fundamentally something that varies with table. What I can say is that I played it from 5-13 (start to brutal barrage) with Lodestone Lure and Mark of Storm, which allowed me to strand enemies pretty effectively. My experience is that, while it is fairly potent control, it is single target control that takes a standard action and only delays dealing with a threat. Also, it only does that with enemies that are entirely melee. If they have a ranged option, they can still use that. At higher levels (or even specific enemies at low levels) they might have longer range teleports. So it is strong, but not unreasonably so in my experience.

I will add that I don't see any reading in which option 2 is a thing, and I think that actually renders the power quite weak.

Comment: It may be useful to support this with the *RC* definition of *move* (200). I suspect that the definition of *move* that this answer uses without any accompanying textual support may be why responses to this answer have been muted.

Comment: thanks for the advice, citation added

Comment: I'm leaning toward this answer because of that *RC* definition but even more because of your experience. However, it's useful to actually address the issues a question poses (again! `:-)`). In this case, that may mean answering *How can the* lodestone lure *power's Hit entries be rephrased to reflect a new balanced reading?* with something like *Until the end of your next turn, the target can't move or be moved from its current location  by any means (including teleportation) unless all of that movement continuously sees the target end up adjacent to the battlemind* or something.

Comment: That is, it's obvious to you, an experienced player who had that definition of *move* in their head already what the power's Hit entry means, but what the power means should also be clear to an *inexperienced* reader (*and* his inexperienced DM!), and, based on my research, the way the power's currently phrased, it isn't.

Comment: I've been trying to think how to really say this, but I can't think of a way other than just restating the game definition of "move" in the power. Which I guess you could, but it's very much not a precedent that I think is good to set, as a general thing. Down that leads to restating things like what pull means. Honestly, the RAW definition I brought up is strong and the option 1 that you provided is still _good_(especially since 3 isn't a great level for battleminds), so I don't think it's a problem if groups run on option 1.